ISO 13849-1 Cat 3 Architecture in safety sensors
Context > In ISO 13849-1 CAT-3 architecture, you need 2 redundant I-L-O (Input-Logic-Output) channels and there has to be a cross monitoring between two redundant logic units. Refer to the image below for CAT-3 system architecture.

Screenshot from ISO 13849-1 standard available on iso.org
Q > Some of the safety sensors available in the market such as safety light curtains/safety Lidars advertise then as PL-d or sometimes even PL-e compliant. PL-e and most of PL-d systems need 2 separate redundant input channels which usually are not available in light curtains/Lidars (e.g.- A safety light curtain receiver has only one set of beam detection sensors OR safety Lidar has only one ToF sensor inside it). If that is the case, how are they claiming to be compliant with PL-d/PL-e architectures?
All of them have 2x OSSD outputs which are redundant & I'm assuming there are 2 separate logic units which might be present inside the body but on the outside I can only see one input channel.

Saurav Kulkarni  Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL).  If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More site rules in the [tour] & [help]) TY

added it. Hope that works

Saurav Kulkarni - Hi, Thanks for adding some text, but that still doesn't give the link to the specific page. || As it says in the site rule, always reference to the best of your ability. Can you add the specific webpage link on iso.org for the ISO 13849-1 standard? And to be clear, is that standard where you copied that image from? TY

For reference, the same question appears to have been asked on the plctalk.net in ISO 13849-1 Cat 3 Architecture in safety sensors. That was found on a search for "ISO 13849-1 CAT-3 system architecture".
